# Dropdown CSS menu contracting

Tags: css, navigation, drop-down-menu

I have implemented a dropdown menu into a website, here:

http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk/

However, The dropdowns themselves seem to contract prematurely. Its sometimes difficult to keep the dropdown open when moving from the initial button onto an option in the dropdown.

Is this a problem with the code or something is affecting it? Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: what browser produce the problem?

Comment: i can reproduce this in ie8 and sometimes in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dropdown divs `.dropdown_Xcolumns` have a top `margin` of `4px`, When the mouse is on these 4px it's breaking the hover (unless it's done really fast!).. remove the top margin and all should be well.

If you want the effect of a gap between the `<li>` and the dropdown `div` - try a top white border on that div

or alternatively, leave the top margin, and add 4px bottom padding to the container `<li>`s to make them meet up better

Answer (score 2):

try to change for  `margin: 4px auto;` to `margin: 2px auto;` for `.dropdown_buildings` in menu.css

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add **padding** to each li element. It increase the active surface area of the hover area. When the user hover over the top nav and the sub-menu appears, the user can move the mouse downwards, and since he is now still within the padding area the hover is still activated.